# iOS Simulator doesn't show prototype cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently learning Objective-C by doing tutorials ("the iOS Apprecente")
Now I need to make a checklist

I added in viewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
```

Normal there stands

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

The next is to go to Storyboard place there a `TableViewController`, give it the name: ChecklistsViewController (Identity inspector > Custom class > class.
I added a label into the first Table view cell. But when I run it there's nothing.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Two separate issues here:

1. The choice of `UIViewController` with your own `IBOutlet` for the table view or a `UITableViewController` is simply a question of whether, in Interface Builder (IB), you added a standard view controller to which you added a table view, or whether you used a table view controller. You use the former if you have other controls on the view in addition to the table view. You'd generally use the latter if the table view is the only thing being presented in that view controller's view. Bottom line, your choice of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` is dictated by how you added the scene in IB. From your description, it sounds like you went down the `UITableViewController` approach, which is fine.
2. In terms of why you're not seeing anything, there are a bunch of possible reasons:

   - Did you specify the cell identifier for your table view cell prototype? Is it the same identifier you're using in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?
   - If you manually added a table view to a standard view controller's view, did you specify the view controller as the `delegate` and `dataSource` for the table view? Also, did you create an `IBOutlet` for the table view itself, hooking that up in IB? (If you used a table view controller in Interface Builder, you don't have to do these steps.)
   - You might want to double-check that the base class for the table view controller was correctly set in IB.
   - Did you implement all of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, notably `numberOfRowsInSection`? If you don't do that, it will conclude that there are no rows, and no cells will be generated.
   - You say that you specified the base class for your view controller in IB to be `ChecklistsViewController`. But in your code snippets, it looks like you're using a custom class called `ViewController`. Make sure you're using the same `UITableViewController` subclass for both.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer a very broad question.

Comment: Thanks for this brief information it works, second dot of point 2 was the solving answer.